# Accessing users starred locations from Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way to access a users google account to retrieve the list of starred locations that they selected in Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

You might try poking around with the `content://com.google.android.maps.StarredItemProvider` provider.  Just query what you need from it using a `ContentResolver`

Comment: I've been looking but I can not find any kind of documentation on the StarredItemProvider. Can you help any?

Comment: That's because it's not intended to be public. It just exists in the Google Maps application. That's why I said "poke around", because you won't be able to (easily) get full documentation about how it works. Was just trying to point out that Google Maps does expose the data, at the above content provider; but it's only used by Google apps (like Maps). That doesn't mean you can't access it too, just that you have to understand it may change out from under you, with no warning -- kind of like using `@*android:...` resources, which are considered "private". And requires reverse engineering :X